# jquery.load() didnt work at the first click when the button is clicked for the first time

Tags: php, jquery

I have a button that once u click, it will insert a new row to the existing table. Problem that i faced is i have to click twice for the first time for new row will be inserted. But after that, every time you click once, the row will be inserted.

button:

```
<input type="button" id="add_po_item" name="add_po_item" value="Add Next PO Item" class="btn" style="width:150px; visibility:visible" onclick="addStock(this, '<?php echo $prod_id; ?>', '<?php echo $poid; ?>'); ">
```

javascript function to add new row:

```
function addStock(obj, stock_id, poid)
{
        var inputs = document.getElementById('counter').value*1;
        var elemName = "hid"+inputs; 

        if(obj.id == 'add_po_item')
        {
            $('#' + elemName).load("grn_additem.php", { inputs: inputs, stock_id: stock_id, poid: poid } );
        }

        inputs++;
        var table = document.getElementById("add");
        var elem = document.createElement("tr");
        elem.id = "hid" + inputs;
        table.appendChild(elem);

        document.getElementById('counter').value = inputs;
}
```

content in grn_additem.php

```
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="ttlM3_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" name="ttlM3_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="border:none; text-align:center" value="0" /></td>
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="m31_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" name="m31_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" onkeyup="calcM3('<?php echo $ctr; ?>')" /></td>
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="m32_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" name="m32_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" onkeyup="calcM3('<?php echo $ctr; ?>')" /></td>
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="m33_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" name="m33_<?php echo $ctr; ?>" onkeyup="calcM3('<?php echo $ctr; ?>')" /></td>
<td width="45">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="144"><input type="text" id="matchcolor<?php echo $ctr; ?>" name="matchcolor<?php echo $ctr; ?>" readonly="readonly" style="background-color:#FF0000" /></td>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery so please don't attach event handlers through the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: jQuery is useful not just for AJAX, but for DOM manipulation as well.

Comment: Does the javascript console show any errors?

Comment: there is no any error given... if i dont use onclick, what should i use?

Comment: `$("#add_po_item").click(addStock)` . Use `this` instead of `obj`. The remaining parameters can be stored as `data-`attributes of the button.

Comment: Oh and please don't use `style = ...` . Use external stylesheets instead.

Comment: i have tried that...it doesnot change anything. i guess something wrong with the load()...it doesnt load for the 1st time...

Comment: Does the network log show anything interesting? In chrome: `F12` -> `Network` -> Clear -> perform testing while observing the log -> analyse the results.

Comment: first time click, it didnt load the grn_additem.php...for the second time, it loads...

Comment: Check if the URL is correct. If so, then it's a server issue.

Comment: yes..the url is correct. if it's wrong it wont run for the second time...

Comment: it's not server issue as well.

Comment: i got it! before data is loaded, i have to create the <tr> for it first. it works now... =)